# Запрет на нажатие кнопки без галочки в чекбоксе

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Как запретить клик по кнопке (`<input type="image">`) если чекбокс не активен (`<input type="checkbox">`)?

Решение должно быть в чистом CSS.

Comment: css не может запрещать действия, на css можно скрыть кнопку, либо показывать другую

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPD

Запретить на css можно, как оказалось, вариант с `pointer-events` в ответе @zenden2k.

Есть 2 варианта без запрета:

### Вариант 1

Скрываем вообще кнопку, пока не стоит галочка

```css
input + button {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + button {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<label for="check">Чекбокс</label>
<input id="check" type="checkbox" />
<button>Кнопка</button>
```

### Вариант 2

Показываем заглушку вместо кнопки пока не стоит галочка

```css
input + button {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + button {
  display: inline;
}
input:checked + button + button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="check">Чекбокс</label>
<input id="check" type="checkbox" />
<button>Кнопка</button>
<button disabled="disabled">Кнопка</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
input+input {
  opacity: .5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input:checked+input {
  opacity: 1.0;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="image">
```

Comment: А если кнопка выполнена так:
<input type="image" src="img/middle/2.2/button!!!.png" alt="Watch"> 
а чекбокс:
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox">
можно как-то применить второй вариант ответа  ?